# Unconstrained optimal control - $J = \int_0^{t_1} (x^2 + ux + \frac{1}{2} u^2) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, real-numbers, optimal-control

I've been given the following problem to solve, and I'm having a lot of difficulty in understanding what I can do.

> The system $\dot x = x + u$, where $u = u(t)$ is not subject to any constraint, is to be controlled from $x(0) = 3$ to $x(t_1) = 2$, where $t_1$ is unspecified, such that $$J = \int_0^{t_1} (x^2 + ux + \frac{1}{2} u^2) dt$$ is minimised. Find the optimal control.

Basically, I've tried to follow my lecture notes as closely as possible, but I'm not sure whether I'm doing the right things.

To begin, I've set $f_0 = x^2 + ux + \frac{1}{2} u^2$, and $f_1 = x + u$. Then, I get the following Hamiltonian equation;
$$H = -f_0 + \psi f_1 = -(x^2 + ux + \frac{1}{2} u^2) + \psi x + \psi u$$

Now, from my lecture notes, I know that $\frac{\partial H}{\partial u} = 0$, and $\dot \psi = \frac{- \partial H}{\partial x}$. This gives me two equations;
$$\dot \psi = 2x + u - \psi$$
$$0 = -x - u + \psi$$

Now, here's where I might be making my mistakes. I added the two equations together, in order to cancel out terms;
$$\dot \psi = x$$
Solving this equation, I get $\psi = \frac{1}{2} x^2 + A$.

However, at this point, I'm not too sure where I am supposed to go. Do I substitute this equation for $\psi$ into my previous equations, in order to solve for $u$??

Any assistance would be fantastic, even if it's just a link to a few examples. I'm rather lost in where to proceed with this question.

Comment: There is one more condition on $\psi$. Namely, $\psi(t_1) = 0$, since in your case $\Psi(z)$ function is identically zero (defined from $J=\Psi(x(T))+\int^T_0 L(x(t),u(t)) \,dt$). Note that $\dot{\psi} = \frac{d\psi}{dt}$ but not $\frac{d\psi}{dx}$, and hence your solution of the equation $\dot{\psi} = x$ is not correct.

Comment: Also you can use your initial system. Substitute $x + u$ for $\dot{x}$ in your second equation obtaining $\dot{x} = \psi$, from this and your result we have $\frac{d(\psi + x)}{dt} = \psi + x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I've worked it out!!

First, we maximise $H$ by considering $\frac{\partial H}{\partial u} = 0$. Then, we have;
$$0 = \frac{\partial H}{\partial U} = -x - u + \psi$$
$$\implies u = \psi - x$$

Now, we can also note that $\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial u^2} = -1 < 0$, so $H$ is definitely maximised.

Then, we consider $\dot \psi = \frac{-\partial H}{\partial x}$;
$$\dot \psi = \frac{-\partial H}{\partial x} = 2x + u - \psi$$.

Now, we recall that the optimal state equation is $\dot x = x + u$;
$$\implies \dot x = x + (\psi - x)$$
$$\implies \dot x = \psi$$

Then, we have;
$$\ddot x = \dot \psi = 2x + u - \psi = 2x + (\psi - x) - \psi = x$$
$$\implies x(t) = Ae^t + Be^{-t}$$
$$\therefore \psi = Ae^t - Be^{-t}$$
$$\therefore u = -2Be^{-t}$$

Now that we have equations for $u$, $x$, and $\psi$, we can substitute into $H$. I'd rather avoid writing all this out, so I'll just state that the result is $H = -2AB$. Now, I would like some input as to the justification here, but from lecture notes, we can basically use this result to see that $AB = 0$.

Taking $AB = 0$, we then have either $A = 0$ or $B = 0$.

If we take $B=0$, then we have that $x(t) = 3e^t$ (from our initial conditions). Then;
$$x(t_1) = 2 = 3e^{t_1}$$
$$\implies t_1  = -\ln(\frac{3}{2}) < 0$$
So, $B$ cannot be zero.

If we take $A = 0$, then we have that $x(t) = 3e^{-t}$. Thus, we have $t_1 = \ln(\frac{3}{2}) > 0$, so we're satisfied our conditions!!

Then, we have that $u^*(t) = -6e^{-t}$ is the optimal control, with $x^*(t) = 3e^{-t}$. It then follows that $J = \frac{5}{2}$.

Apart from that jump of setting $AB = 0$, I'm fairly confident with this answer.

Comment: I don't know how to tell you this, but you have a negative time

Comment: Downes, I am not sure this is right, I have an alternative answer

Comment: $\ln(1.5) \approx 0.41$, is it not?? If that's the case, I'm not sure how my time could be negative.

Comment: Because then, we've got $t \in [0,0.41]$, so the problem should be valid. I verified my answer with the initial conditions, and everything seems to check out, so I'm not sure where my error is (if I have indeed made one).

Comment: Why did you edit your answer from $\bf{J} =\frac52$ to $\bf{J}=1$?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7Bln+3%2F2%7D+%28%283e%5E%7B-t%7D%29%5E2+%2B+%28-6e%5E%7B-t%7D%29%283e%5E%7B-t%7D%29%2B%5Cfrac12+%28-6e%5E%7B-t%7D%29%5E2+dt
( \int_0^{ln 3/2} ((3e^{-t})^2 + (-6e^{-t})(3e^{-t})+\frac12 (-6e^{-t})^2 dt )

Comment: When I put it back into Wolfram just before, I got an answer of 1. I'll be doing it on paper when I get home to confirm.

Comment: Never mind, I had made the mistake of putting the formula into Wolfram without the $x^2$ term, I just had it as $x$. $\frac{5}{2}$ should be the correct answer for $J$, assuming I've done everything else correctly.

Comment: It seems you have done it right then! Best of luck!

Comment: @Jack Any ideas on Q3?

Comment: I have $\psi_1=Ae^{-3t} + \psi_2t$, and $\psi_2=\psi_1t-Be^{-3t}$ am I on the right track?

Comment: There's something in lecture notes that gives you an equation for the switching function - I think it's in Week 9 of the notes?? Anyway, it allows you to determine a solution really easily, and you can get time as a function of the constants of the equation for $\psi_2$, which will be arbitrary, but that's fine!!

Comment: @Jack Oh I have been looking at the wrong examples noooo!

Comment: I feel like people should just use the appropriate Facebook group for questions like this, instead of here, but hey~

Comment: @Jack What do you mean? Hi though I agree

Comment: You aren't in that facebook group though, assuming @Algebra was saying you are jack downes

Comment: @thisismuchhealthier noone is called Jack in the group. Yeah use page 8 from module 9.

Comment: oops I thought it'd be the 3rd Year Math Group, not a group specific to this course!! :D

Comment: @Jack But this is first year course...???

Comment: Can you link to third year??

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/groups/238047439673279/

I generally used this group, but it isn't very active.